# IIS appwhen adding a binding. servername.domain.com/app works, but appname.domain.com/app doesn't

Tags: asp.net, iis, binding

I have a server whose sole purpose is to host a prebuilt IIS app from a vendor.

The server has been built, IIS is working, and with everything installed, the app is accessible from http://servername.domain.com/app

I want to add an alternate URL, to be http://appname.domain.com/app, for ease of use and cleanliness.

I added the binding on both ports 80 and 443 with our site cert, using all unassigned IPs and none of the boxes ticked.

Despite changing nothing but the bindings, I'm getting the following error attempting to use the newly bound URL:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +6466184
   Xtraction.Web.Auth.Authenticate.HasSingleActiveProvider() +185
   Xtraction.Web.Auth.Authenticate.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +106
   Xtraction.Web.PageBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +17
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3785
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is a code problem caused by your changes to the hosting configuration. You will need to contact the vendor to get support on this. Only they know what their code is doing (method `Xtraction.Web.Auth.Authenticate.HasSingleActiveProvider()`).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error information you provided, the reason I retrieved is that your application pool is not set up to use a service account, which prevents you from logging into Xtraction.

You need to set the application pool to use the Windows service account:

> 1. Go to IIS Manager > Servers > Application Pools > Xtraction
> 2. Click the Advanced Settings link in the right pane
> 3. Go to the Identity section, if it's set to Network Service, then click the ellipsis on the right
> 4. Change to "Custom Account" and enter your service account - this must have dbowner (or at least db_datareader and db_datawriter)
>    permissions on the Xtraction database
> 5. Click OK and restart the application pool (or execute iisreset). You should now be able to log in to Xtraction

For more information, you can refer to this [link](https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/Cannot-login-to-Xtraction-when-Application-Pool-is-not-set-to-use-a-service-account?language=en_US).